# Recorrer un Array de Json para volcarlo en una tabla html

Tags: javascript, html, json

He obtenido un Json parseando con la siguiente estrucctura:
`obj ->campo->[0]` y dentro del elemento 0 me encontraría (anotación, fechat, fechac,resultado) y así sucesivamente varios elementos.
Quisiera volcar los datos a una tabla html.

```html
<table border="1">
<thead class="tituloCrear2b">
 <tr>
  <th>Fecha.I</th>
  <th>Fecha.Ca</th>
  <th>Resultado</th>
  <th>Anot</th>                 
 </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la estructura a la que te refieres (deberías detallar más tus preguntas y poner cuanta más información y código mejor) es como en el siguiente ejemplo, puedes conseguirlo con la siguiente función:

```js
let obj = {
    campo: [
        {
            anotacion: "1",
            fechat: "2",
            fechac: "3",
            resultado: "4"
        },
        {
            anotacion: "5",
            fechat: "6",
            fechac: "7",
            resultado: "8"
        }
    ]
}

function rellenarTabla(obj) {
  let tbody = document.getElementById('mTableBody');
  obj.campo.forEach((c) => {
      let filaNueva = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + c.fechat + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + c.fechac + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + c.resultado + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + c.anotacion + '</td>' +
                      '</tr>';
    tbody.innerHTML += filaNueva;
  });
}
rellenarTabla(obj);
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead class="tituloCrear2b">
 <tr>
  <th id="fechaI">Fecha.I</th>
  <th id="fechaCa">Fecha.Ca</th>
  <th id="resultado">Resultado</th>
  <th id="anotacion">Anot</th>                 
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="mTableBody">
</tbody>
</table>
```